# JGAP Robocode User Guide

Tags: java, robocode, jgap

I've had a look at the JGAP package from the robocode website and I have been getting problems when attempting to set it up. It seems that some of the files that are talked about are not actually in the download. For instance the line on the website says:-

```
"MyRobot that resides in subdirectory myrobots. In the above call, Aspirant3285 is used"
```

However the above subdirectory or robot is not in the download also when attempting to run the JAR files the error bellow is shown:

```
"[main] WARN  org.jgap.robocode.EvolveRobot  - File not found"
```

Anyone who can give me a link to a tutorial or some advice on this fix would be much appreciated if further details are required feel free to ask.....

Regards..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure on the example from the website how the structure is set up as I was unable to get this running myself.

I've created a small example of how to get the two libraries integrated with each other and running in a very simple application to write, generate, battle and evolve a robot population which may help to get you going in the right direction.

https://github.com/samternent/robocode-jgap-template/