# JGAP Genetic Programming - Classification

Tags: java, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, genetic-programming, jgap

I would like to find out if there are any tutorials which can help me get started using JGAP to solve and evolve a classification problem.

Example I want to solve [this dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Balloons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `JGAP` tutorial available on [SourceForge](http://jgap.sourceforge.net/doc/tutorial.html).

Another [here](https://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/jgap-a-firstsimple-tutorial/) and a [blog](http://jcraane.blogspot.com/2009/02/introduction-to-genetic-algorithms-with.html).

If you want to test your mettle with [robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/) and JGAP you can get started:
[JGAP Robocode User Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118639/jgap-robocode-user-guide).

Comment: Thank you. Those links are pretty easy to follow and very useful, however I do not follow the gene representation part. So I need to represent using a n-ary tree. Terminal set being True/False, and Functional set being Colour, Size etc. Now how would I go about creating this Gene? How would I determine the arity for each Functional Set node?

Comment: @RK2015 The questions you pose here are outside of the scope of the question statement. It is easier for future users to find information if we limit the scope of our Questions and Answers to provide only the most relevant information. I suggest you ask a new Question with the next steps that you find yourself curious about. Don't forget to post any code that you have where you have attempted to solve the problem!